# Is there a way to still have zombie villagers from zombie spawners?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm halfway through building a villager cure station from a zombie spawner however since 1.11 zombie villagers don't spawn there anymore...

Is there still a way to maybe change this feature back through the use of a datapack or something?

I'm playing on 1.14.1 Pre-release.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A spawner can choose between entities from an arbitrarily big set that you specify.

For example if you want 95% of entities from a spawner to be zombies and 5% to be zombie villagers, you can use this command:

```
/setblock ~ ~ ~ spawner{SpawnPotentials:[{Entity:{id:"zombie"},Weight:19},{Entity:{id:"zombie_villager"},Weight:1}]}
```

This isn't quite the same behaviour as it used to have in old versions, for example I'm pretty sure that it's slower, but you can adjust all the parameters you find [here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Chunk_format#Block_entity_format) ([archive](https://minecraft.wiki/w/index.php?title=Chunk_format&oldid=1367272#Block_entity_format)) however you like.

<sub>(Omitting the `Weight` parameters gives 100% of the spawn probability to the first entity type.)</sub>

Comment: I've been testing it and I'm not getting any zombie villagers. Here is a screenshot of the nbt data of the spawner: https://imgur.com/a/aPAQP7j As you can see it also has a spawnData entry, is this a problem?

Comment: Nevermind a villager just spawned. however I feel like it's less than 5% at this point.

Comment: 5% is one in 20, it takes a while. I also tested it, it really does take a while, especially because the spawning is slower than for normal spawners, if you don't specify anything in that regard, but after about 10-15 spawns, I got a regular zombie villager and a baby zombie villager at once.