# Is there a way to still have zombie villagers from zombie spawners in 1.17?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm halfway through building a villager cure station from a zombie spawner however since 1.11 zombie villagers don't spawn there anymore...

Is there still a way to maybe change this feature back through the use of a datapack or commands or something
I tried this command   /setblock ~ ~ ~ spawner{SpawnPotentials:[{Entity:{id:"zombie"},Weight:19},{Entity:{id:"zombie_villager"},Weight:1}]}   and it says could not sit the block is there something wrong?
I'm playing on 1.17

Comment: The answer to this question should help. https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/351044/is-there-a-way-to-still-have-zombie-villagers-from-zombie-spawners

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to still have zombie villagers from zombie spawners?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/351044/is-there-a-way-to-still-have-zombie-villagers-from-zombie-spawners)

Comment: This question is a 95%+ verbatim copypasta from the question I provided as a duplicate.

Comment: I tried the same thing, and it didn't work for me. It says cant set this entity or something like that,thats why i asked if it changes in 1.17

Comment: If you only want zombie villagers to spawn you could do it manually by giving yourself a spawner and then using the zombie villager spawn egg on the spawner.

Comment: No that will ruin it i don't need it like that, i need a method just like this https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/351044/is-there-a-way-to-still-have-zombie-villagers-from-zombie-spawners , or someone try the same thing and see if it works for him in 1.17

Comment: But why copy/paste the other question if your question is unique? Can you edit your question so that we know the particulars of your situation, what you're trying to accomplish, what you've tried, etc.?

Comment: It would be good to know what the error is when you use the line of code from the other question's answer.

Comment: I've edited my question, but my question is not uniqe, So I asked if it changed in game update 1.17 or if there was a mistake I made. Can u try the command and see if it dont work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Your command may be outdated. I used a command generator such as [MCStacker](https://mcstacker.net/) to generate a working command for 1.17:

```
/setblock ~ ~ ~ spawner{SpawnData:{id:"minecraft:zombie"},SpawnPotentials:[{Weight:19,Entity:{id:"minecraft:zombie"}},{Weight:1,Entity:{id:"minecraft:zombie_villager"}}]} replace
```

Comment: It didn't work it says the same thing,, could not set the block, maybe i got it wrong should i just try this command or use that command generator you talking about?

Comment: If you are setting the spawner at the position of an existing spawner, it will fail. To workaround this, you can change `replace` to `destroy` (at the end of the command)

Comment: Also didn't work when i put it replace it says could not set the block when i make it destroy it replaced by pig spawner(nothing)

Comment: Also didn't work when i put it replace it says could not set the block when i make it destroy it replaced by pig spawner(nothing)